# How to set minimum height for a Windows 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-8.1-universal

For **Windows 10 UWP** apps we have [ApplicationView.SetPreferredMinSize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize) and **500 x 500** limitation for maximum minimum window size. But what about **Windows 8.1** apps - is there any similar API to set the minimum width and height of the app window?

It seems like the default minimum height of the blank Windows 8.1 app is noticeably larger then height of the blank Windows 10 UWP app and I can't find where it may be set or changed.

Comment: win8.x apps were designed to always run in fullscreen, so there is no such API

Comment: @magicandre1981 that is true for sure. The thing is on Windows 10 they are running in a window mode now with some minimum height and width restriction applied, so I was wondered is it possible to change this min height and width for them now.

Comment: the answer of Jay is what I would also suggest. Use reflection to get the API (here you are on Win10 and call it). In Win8 this fails so ignore it and run the app in fullscreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondered is it possible to change this min height and width for them now.

Yeah, we can use reflection to call `ApplicationView.SetPreferredMinSize` method at Runtime within Windows 8.1 app to achieve what you want. Following is a simple sample:

```
var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
var setPreferredMinSizeMethod = appView.GetType().GetRuntimeMethod("SetPreferredMinSize", new Type[] { typeof(Size) });

if (setPreferredMinSizeMethod != null)
{
    setPreferredMinSizeMethod.Invoke(appView, new object[] { new Size(300, 300) });
}
```

After using this approach, you can change the minimum height and width of your app:[image]

But please note that on Windows 10, Windows 8.1 app's ApplicaitonView is mainly controlled by system. If not necessary, please do not use reflection to do this.